# Suppress warning in Rider for a specific project

Tags: c#, suppress-warnings, jetbrains-rider

I am working on a project that only contains Models and I have a lot of properties like this one:

```
public string FromReversed
{
    get
    {
        return From.ReverseString();
    }
    #if MyDirective
    [Obsolte("Only in here because if the setter is not included the this property will not be saved into mongoDB")
    set { }
    #endif
}
```

When using the Rider IDE I get this warning: `'value' parameter is not used` I can disable that warning by placing this comment `// ReSharper disable once ValueParameterNotUsed` on top of that property or by placing this comment `// ReSharper disable ValueParameterNotUsed` at the top of my file. **Now my question is how can I disable that warning for the entire project?**

I have attempted these 4 things with no success:

1. **If I do `'.' + Enter` and then change the severity of that warning from warning to 'Do not show':** [image]
   Doing so makes the warning go away but I want that warning to also appear in other projects. I just want to ignore that warning for this specific project withtout having to go to every file and place `// ReSharper disable ValueParameterNotUsed`.
2. I have tried placing this attributes on my GlobalUsing.cs file:

```
global using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;
global using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// This works if I place this attribute on top of the class
[assembly: SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "ValueParameterNotUsed")]
```

3. I tried placing `resharper_value_parameter_not_used=none` line on `.editorconfig` based on this article https://dunnhq.com/posts/2020/codeinspections/. But I am probably naming the property incorrectly.
4. I have tried placing the id of that warning because it contains no number on the  tag of my .csproj file like so:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>1701;1702;ValueParameterNotUsed</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Alt solution: You could perhaps use a *discard* to clean this up on a case-by-case basis: `set => _ = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file contains the global settings for Rider in Windows 11: `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Rider<Version>\GlobalSettings.DotSettings`

I noticied that when I changed the inspection severity like this:

[image]]

Then this line was added to my `GlobalSettings.DotSettings` file

```xml
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=UnusedAutoPropertyAccessor_002EGlobal/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
```

The solution was to move that configuration from `GlobalSettings.DotSettings` file to `MyProject.csproj.DotSettings`. And now those changes only affect the specific project that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use an `AssemblyAttrubute` definition in your `.csproj` to achieve this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>ReSharper</_Parameter1>
    <_Parameter2>ValueParameterNotUsed</_Parameter2>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Did not work :/ . Thanks for the help

Comment: Agh, what a shame. I've used this before with success for other things, i.e. `InternalsVisibleTo`. Quite surprised it's not working.

Comment: Tried this using `[assembly: SuppresMessage(...)]` and it also didn't work. Rider team seems uninterested in supporting the feature https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-463998